# Add coastline when plotting faceted arrays in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, cartography

I put together a toy example below.

My question is, how can I added coastlines (much like you can get from the `maps` package to the faceted plots below?

I can do this with `contour()` and `filled.contour()`, but I'm not sure of how to go about this with `ggplot2`-style plotting when using facet layers. I have no problem plotting coasts when I have a single plot.

You can download the netCDF file "sst.mon.anom.nc" from NOAA [here](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/fileServer/Datasets/kaplan_sst/sst.mon.anom.nc) (~ 10mb).

```
library(ncdf4)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

# The data is 5x5 degree reconstructed sea-surface temperature anomalies.
# Exciting stuff.
sst <- ncvar_get(nc = nc_open("sst.mon.anom.nc"),
                 varid = "sst",
                 start = c(1, 1, 1),
                 count = c(-1, -1, -1))

# Drawing out four layers from the sst array.
d1 <- melt(sst[, , 1])
d1$drought <- rep("d1", dim(d1)[1])
d3 <- melt(sst[, , 3])
d3$drought <- rep("d3", dim(d3)[1])
d5 <- melt(sst[, , 5])
d5$drought <- rep("d5", dim(d5)[1])
d6 <- melt(sst[, , 6])
d6$drought <- rep("d6", dim(d6)[1])

# Combining the layers into a single data.frame:
d <- rbind(d1, d3, d5, d6)
names(d) <- c("lon", "lat", "ERSST", "layer")

p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ERSST))
print(p + geom_tile() + 
      scale_fill_gradient2(high = "red", low = "blue") + 
      facet_wrap(~ layer) )
```

[image: Output from the above script]

Many thanks!

P.S. Also, I just noticed that the color legend ordering is upside down. Hmm...

Comment: Is there a 'catch' for installing the `ncdf4` library? I receive the following message when I try to install: "ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ncdf4’" and "installation of package ‘ncdf4’ had non-zero exit status".

Comment: It could be a dependency issue. I believe it draws on the netcdf library > 4.1 as a system requirement. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/index.html

Comment: @brews just save the data using `save`, that should make it possible for other people to use `load` to load it into their workspace.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Indeed, I will be sure to do this next time. I had no idea it would be a source of trouble. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of `ggplot2` is that there is no need to perform a specific operation for each facet. Just added a `geom_path` with as `data` the data.frame which contains the coastlines will draw it on all of the facets. See [the documentation of `coord_map`](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_map.html) for an example of using `geom_path` with a polygon set from the `maps` package. Do note that if and only if your grid data and the polygon/polyline data is in the same projection, this will work. Through `coord_map` `ggplot2` supports coordinate transforms out of the box. Alternatively, you can use `spTransform` from the `rgdal` package to perform the coordinate transformation before feeding the data to ggplot2 (I tend to do this).

Comment: Yes, this is what I do when I'm plotting in ggplot2 without faceting. But when faceting, wouldn't the coast data.frame then need whatever variable that I'm faceting by?

Comment: No, if the variable you are faceting with is not present in the map `data.frame`, it will draw the same map on all the facets. You could define the variable your are faceting with, allowing you to draw different maps on different facets. But if you want to draw the same map everywhere, this is not needed.